# How to create a war file from a directory in gradle

Tags: gradle, war

I am writing a task to unzip a war file, remove some jars and then create a war from extracted folder.

```
task unzipWar(type: Copy){
   println 'unzipping the war'
   def warFile = file("${buildDir}/temp/libs/webapps/service-app.war")
   def warOutputDir = file("$buildDir/wartemp")

   from zipTree(warFile)
   into warOutputDir
}

task deleteJars(type: Delete){
   println 'deleting the logging jars'    
   file("$buildDir/wartemp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar").delete();
   file("$buildDir/wartemp/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar").delete();
   file("$buildDir/wartemp/WEB-INF/lib/logback-core-1.1.7.jar").delete();   
}

task createWar(type: War){  
   destinationDir = file("$buildDir")
   baseName = "service-app"
   from "$buildDir/wartemp"
   dependsOn deleteJars
}
```

For some reason, the jars are not getting deleted and the war file is getting created which only includes `MANIFEST.MF` and nothing else. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing to note, is that your `createWar` task depends on `deleteJars`task, but `deleteJars` doesn't depend on `unzipWar`. It seems, that if you call the `createWar` task it won't call `unzipWar` task and there will be nothing to copy or delete. Note that you have a `MANIFEST.MF` file, because it was generated by `createWar` task.

And the second thing is that you are trying to delete some files in the configuration stage of the build, though your `unzipWar` will do it's job in the execution phase. So your delete task will try to delete this files just before they are even unzipped. You can read about build lifecycle [in the official userguide](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html). So you need to rewrite your `deleteJars` task, to configure it properly. Take a look into the [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Delete.html), it has an example how to do it.

So if you call a

```
file("$buildDir/wartemp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar").delete();
```

it tries to delete your files at the time it's called, because it's not a task property, but an action at the configuration.

To configure it you have to do something like:

```
task deleteJars(type: Delete) {
  delete "$buildDir/wartemp/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar", "$buildDir/wartemp/WEB-INF/lib/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar", "$buildDir/wartemp/WEB-INF/lib/logback-core-1.1.7.jar"
}
```